# Jad file does not get download on SAMSUNG Galaxy S i9000

Tags: android, java-me

I have developed one j2me application, then I copied it jad file into my server. I tried to download that jad file from server using  SAMSUNG Galaxy S i9000 but it displays jad file content as it is. Instead of downloading the jad file application from the server. But it gets downloaded successfully on my Nokia 7020. 
What could be issue here.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Android mobile browser doesn't support to download via OTA for `.jad` files. Basically `.jad` file describe the information about MIDlet. That's the reason for its showing the content of MIDlet while you downloading.  Nokia supports to download the `.jad` files via OTA.

Comment: So,  what is alternate way for downloading jad file to Samsung Anroid mobiles.

Comment: Why you want jad file on samsung mobile? Its not supported on this mobile.

Comment: Is there any other file type which could be supported by samsung...so that it can be build as a j2me application.

Comment: You can convert .jad or .jar file to .apk file. Look on this [netmite convertor](http://netmite.com/android/srv/2.0/getapk.php). But I dont know how long its work. I didn't use before.